# Resetting the form in the controller gives an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a reset button in my controller. I'm a newbie to Angular JS.

```
 $scope.reset = function() {
     $scope.address = "";
     $scope.provisiondetails={};
     $scope.provisiondetails.LocationModel = '0';
     $scope.memberdetails.search = '0';
 }
```

But, when I try this, it actually gives an error. 
Here, I want to reset the values of all the form fields to empty, except for

```
$scope.provisiondetails.LocationModel = '0';
$scope.memberdetails.search = '0';
```

which are radio buttons, but this is generating an error. How can I resolve this? 
**Edit** :
I get an undefined error. Since I have set the               `$scope.provisiondetails={};` and suddenly set the default radio button value               `$scope.provisiondetails.LocationModel = '0';`, I get undefined error.

Comment: It would be helpful for questions like these if you reproduced the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [Plunk](http://plnkr.co).

Answer (score 1):

Have a default values for your state:

```
var defaults = {
    LocationModel: '0',
    SomeOtherProp: 'fooo'
};

$scope.provisiondetails = defaults;
```

And then just reset it to default:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.address = "";
    $scope.provisiondetails = defaults;
    $scope.memberdetails.search = '0';
};
```

Otherwise, you will get error when trying to access not existing property of object.

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to see more of your code. However, if it's just the error you are describing it may be resolved by doing this:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
     $scope.address = "";
     $scope.provisiondetails={
         LocationModel: '0';
     };
     $scope.memberdetails.search = '0';
 }
```